# Updating to Firebase iOS SDK 9.0.0 fails (Invalid diagnostics signature)

Tags: swift, firebase

My iOS-App worked like a charm with Firebase 8.15.0.

Now I changed the Firebase package dependencies to version "9.0.0 - Next major" and get a lot of errors, which I can't link to the breaking changes related to this major release.

I already cleaned the build folder, restarted Xcode and my MacBook, but nothing helped.

Most likely the underlying problem has to do with the warning "Could not read serialized diagnostics file: error("Invalid diagnostics signature")":

[image: Build Errors]

Comment: Try removing DerivedData. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62566649/could-not-read-serialized-diagnostics-file-invalid-file-invalid-diagnostics-si

Comment: Thank you for your tip, but I removed DerivedData, removed and reinstalled Firebase from SPM and even did a fresh Xcode installation. 
I also tried all other tips from your link. 
The errors are still the same. 
The same code with Firebase 8.15.0 compiles fine.

Comment: Are you able to share a reproducible example?

Comment: Yep, an issue at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues would be perfect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of Google we found out that there are cases where using "import FirebaseFirestoreSwift" is not enough when using FireStore, but "import FirebaseFirestore" has to be added to the file too.

Even if you did not add "FirebaseFirestore" as a Swift Package this will compile then.